# clang error with linker argument '-fuse-ld=-debugger-tuning=lldb'

Tags: bazel

When attempting to build protobuf, via Bazel's `rules_proto/rules_go` I get an error regarding the linker name argument.

Error output from clang:

```
clang: error: invalid linker name in argument '-fuse-ld=-debugger-tuning=lldb'
```

This used to work fine, I did upgrade XCode and can only assume something on my machine has changed.

Using an Intel Mac running MacOS 13.3 (22E252)

```
$ clang --version
Apple clang version 14.0.3 (clang-1403.0.22.14.1)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin22.4.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
$ which -a clang
/usr/bin/clang
/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang
```

What would I be able to do to get a working environment again other then resetting machine to factory settings?

I expected the protoc binary to be built as it still does on other machines.

Comment: Make sure you are using latest versions Bazel version. Similar issue reported here: https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/16286 and fix was provided in this PR: https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/pull/15006.
Hope this will help. Thanks!